# pymongo insert W=2 , J=True speed up

Tags: python, mongodb

Im using python 2.7.8 and pymongo 2.7
and the mongoDB server is a ReplicaSet group one primary two secondary .
the mognodb server is built on AWS server EBS:500GB, IOPS3000 .

I want to know is there any way to speed up the insert.when W=2, j=True
Using pymongo to insert a million of files takes a lot of time
and i know that if i use the W=0 it will speed up ,but it isn't safe
So any suggestion ? Please help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `W=0` is deprecated. This is the older model of MongoDB (pre-3.0), which they don't recommend using any more.

Using MongoDB as a file storage system also isn't a great idea; but, you can consider using [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) if that's the case.

I assume you're trying some sort of mass-import, and you don't have many (or any) readers right now; in which case, you will be okay if any reader sees some, but not all, of the documents.

You have a couple of options:

- set `j=False`. MongoDB will return more quickly (before the documents are committed to the journal), at the potential risk of documents being lost if the DB crashes.
- set `W=1`. If replication is slow, this will only wait until one of the nodes (the primary) has the data before returning.

If you do need strong consistency requirements (readers seeing everything inserted so far), neither of these options will help.

Comment: Thank you for  your help

Answer (score -1):

You can use unordered or ordered [bulk inserts](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html)

This speeds up things alot. May be also you take a look at my [muBulkOps](http://miloncdn.appspot.com/docs/mongoUtils/mongoUtils.helpers.html) a wraper of pymongo bulk operations.

Comment: @周辰彩 may be then you can mark my answer as the acceptable one as it seems people here din't like it much and degraded it, although the link I provided points to mongoDB's official site and will never die, not until the product dies any way:-)